# After Effects: How to change a property of an object based on the color or a pixel?

Tags: after-effects

In Adobe After Effects, how do I change a property of an object (for example the opacity) based on the color of a pixel at a specific location (of another object).

The application is that I want to cover/uncover a part (by changing a layers opacity) if a specific pixel in another layer turns to a specific color.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sampleImage() function to get a specific pixel color.

This expression is rather slow, so just know that it will affect render times. This link will be useful: https://www.motionscript.com/design-guide/sample-image.html

For example, here's an expression that will change the opacity depending on the luma value of the pixel in the middle of the screen:

```
var target = thisComp.layer("video");
// sampleImage() returns an array with R,G,B,Alpha values
var color = target.sampleImage(transform.position, [width, height]/2, true, time)
// get the luma by averaging the 3 channel values (there are more scientific ways to do this, but this is quick and simple)
var luma = (color[0] + color[1] + color[2]) / 3
// divide the luma by 255 if you work in 8bits project
var luma_value = luma / 255;
// use the 0-1 value as an opacity percentage.
luma_value * 100;
```